# Resume the previous aborted COPY in CQL

Tags: csv, copy, cassandra, cql

When importing a large csv file into a Cassandra table using the `COPY` command provided in CQL, there are cases that some of the fields are mis-typed which causes errors like the following:

```
Bad Request: line 1:1033 no viable alternative at input ','
Aborting import at record #277561 (line 277562). Previously-inserted values still present.
277561 rows imported in 8 minutes and 20.296 seconds.
```

After identifying and fixing the mis-typed fields, the next thing is to port the rest of the csv file into the table.  Can I know is there good way to resume the previous aborted COPY such that previously inserted rows will not be re-inserted again?  Or, is it possible to perform `COPY` from a specified line of a csv file instead of the beginning of a csv file?

Comment: Why just not remove the lines you know you've already inserted?

Comment: Because the csv file is very big, editing it and storing it takes a long time :(

Comment: Check [csvfix](https://code.google.com/p/csvfix/) out. It can remove all the lines after a specified line into a separate file, sounds like it would be useful for you.

Comment: Tried csvfix, but it's still slow :~

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [parameter list](http://www.datastax.com/docs/1.1/references/cql/COPY) doesn't seem to have an option for specifying what line to start on in the file, so it appears you cant specify where to start. If you think this would be useful you could report your issue and ask for the implementation of such functionality using the [Cassandra JIRA](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA).

But, that kind of functionality seems redundant, you could just edit the csv file by removing the data you know has already been inserted into cassandra.